# 1D numpy array to float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to convert a 1D numpy array to a simple float (no array).
How is that done? Here is my current code with the variable 'acc'.

```
print type(acc)
print acc.shape

>>> <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> (1,)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
float(acc)
```

To make it a float? Seems to be working here:

```
a = np.array([1])
print a.shape
print type(a)
print float(a)
```

yields

```
(1,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
1.0
```

Comment: There are situations where this doesn't work. Like mine...